# I need to modify a string of text in a loop so that the program should copy paste same string but with a number incremented

Tags: java, python, regex, awk, sed

I need this link to be modified and copy pasted again with number increased like examples shown below

```
www.example.org/images?ID=7497&page=1&CategoryID=1&pagetype=null
www.example.org/images?ID=7497&page=1&CategoryID=2&pagetype=null
www.example.org/images?ID=7497&page=1&CategoryID=3&pagetype=null
www.example.org/images?ID=7497&page=1&CategoryID=4&pagetype=null
www.example.org/images?ID=7497&page=1&CategoryID=5&pagetype=null

----------------------till-1400---------------------------

www.example.org/images?ID=7497&page=1&CategoryID=1400&pagetype=null
```

I need these links to be in increasing order of number till 1400 like the example above.

Solution in any language is fine, i just cant think of logic to do it.
    Sed. Awk. Regex. Python. Java. Anything would** do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you wish to write a simple for loop, maybe:

```
output = ""

for i in range(1400):
    output += 'www.example.org/images?ID=7497&page=' + str(i+1) + '&CategoryID=1&pagetype=null\n'

print(output)
```

#### Output

```
www.example.org/images?ID=7497&page=1&CategoryID=1&pagetype=null
www.example.org/images?ID=7497&page=2&CategoryID=1&pagetype=null
...
www.example.org/images?ID=7497&page=1399&CategoryID=1&pagetype=null
www.example.org/images?ID=7497&page=1400&CategoryID=1&pagetype=null
```

Answer (score 1):

Groovy:

```
[1..1400].each { println "www.example.org/images?ID=7497&page=1&CategoryID=${it}&pagetype=null" }
```

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk 'BEGIN {for(i=1;i<=1400;i++) print "www.example.org/images?ID=7497&page=1&CategoryID="i"&pagetype=null"}'
www.example.org/images?ID=7497&page=1&CategoryID=1&pagetype=null
www.example.org/images?ID=7497&page=1&CategoryID=2&pagetype=null
www.example.org/images?ID=7497&page=1&CategoryID=3&pagetype=null
www.example.org/images?ID=7497&page=1&CategoryID=4&pagetype=null
www.example.org/images?ID=7497&page=1&CategoryID=5&pagetype=null
www.example.org/images?ID=7497&page=1&CategoryID=6&pagetype=null
www.example.org/images?ID=7497&page=1&CategoryID=7&pagetype=null
www.example.org/images?ID=7497&page=1&CategoryID=8&pagetype=null
www.example.org/images?ID=7497&page=1&CategoryID=9&pagetype=null
www.example.org/images?ID=7497&page=1&CategoryID=10&pagetype=null
...
...
```